# Relative context-root fro flash application

Tags: apache-flex, flash, blazeds

i' m using BlazeDs.

In services-config.xml we got following configuration of endPoint.

```
<channel-definition id="any-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
</channel-definition>
```

Before compiling flash application i set up context-root as compilaction option.

```
bin\mxmlc  -context-root / -services "flex/services-config.xml" -optimize=true -o ..\..\bin\Messenger.swf Messenger.as
```

In my case this is "/"

And the problem is that messanger.swf is able to pull request if the web application is started as ROOT in tomcat webapps.
I mean it can only be access by this url localhost:8080/. If i try to move webaplication to another folder -  for example to localhost:8080/myApplication
messenger.swf would not work properly sinse i have to change root_context as well.

So my question how to dinamicly determine context-root in run time, without hardcode it as option of compiler ? 
I want my .war application work properly regardless of it position in webapps folder(url).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I suggest to set the endpoint of your channels at runtime - you cannot change context-root variable during program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [HTTPUtil.as from "Flex Pasta"](http://www.flexpasta.com/index.php/category/utility-classes-that-help-you-deal-with-string-numbers-arrays-and-objects-in-actionscript/)  to get the application URL at runtime and use the functions (`getHostName, getContext, getPort`) to calculate your servlet URL.